# How to compile this lib for usage?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'm new to C programming, and I'm trying to compile [this Simple training example](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files2/gettingstarted-txt.html) with GCC on Ubuntu 12.10.

Looks like fann.h should not be included (as stated on the file itself), so I included fixedfann.h instead.

First attempt (without include, just to see what the compiler will ask for):

```
$ gcc main.c -o output 
/tmp/cckKyM92.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `fann_create_standard'
main.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `fann_set_activation_function_hidden'
main.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `fann_set_activation_function_output'
main.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `fann_train_on_file'
main.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `fann_save'
main.c:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to `fann_destroy'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`fann_create_standard` is on fann.h and fann.c. As fann.h is included by fixedfann.h, and fann.h should not be included directly, I believe I have to compile fann.c and fixedfann.c, and link then (tell me if I'm doing any mistake, I'm still not familiar with this "linking" stuff).

So I did:

```
$ gcc fann/fixedfann.c -o fann/fixedfann.o
fann/fixedfann.c:22:20: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

and then I did:

```
$ gcc fann/fixedfann.c -o fann/fixedfann.o -include fann/include/config.h 
fann/fixedfann.c:22:20: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Now, why it's not finding the config.h file here?

**--update**

Thanks @JonathanLeffler, I could make some steps here. But now I'm stuck at:

```
$ gcc fann/fixedfann.c -o fann/fixedfann.o -I./fann/include/ -lm
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and, with grep, I could not find any reference to `main` on the fann folder... Also no function `_start`, and I don't know who is linking this `crt1.o`... Any idea what's wrong here?

**--update2**

Ok, I got the .o files using Harmeet's Makefile, now I'm trying to link everything.
I created the `main.o` with `gcc -c main.c`, and I tried:

```
gcc -o output main.o fann/fixedfann.o -lm
```

(-lm for the libmath, that is needed) and I got:

```
main.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `fann_train_on_file'
```

This `fann_train_on_file` is on `fann_train_data.c`, so I tried:

```
gcc -o output main.o fann/fixedfann.o fann/fann_train_data.o -lm
```

but I got lots of `multiple definition of...` errors... :/

Looks like `fann_train_data.o` is already included/linked, but if so, why it's not finding `fann_train_on_file`?

**--update3**

I'm still really stuck here... Any idea of which (if any) of this two lines should work?:

```
gcc -o output main.o hello.o fann/fixedfann.o fann/fann_train_data.o -lm
```

or

```
gcc -o output main.o hello.o fann/fixedfann.o -lm
```

**--update for Harmeet**

The output was:

```
$ make
gcc -L./fann -lfann main.o -o main
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `fann_create_standard'
main.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `fann_set_activation_function_hidden'
main.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `fann_set_activation_function_output'
main.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `fann_train_on_file'
main.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `fann_save'
main.c:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to `fann_destroy'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Comment: You probably need `-Ifann` as an extra argument to the GCC command line.

Comment: `$ gcc fann/fixedfann.c -o fann/fixedfann.c -include fann/include/config.h ` and you overwrote your source file ?

Comment: @wildplasser sorry, I mean `$ gcc fann/fixedfann.c -o fann/fixedfann.o -include fann/include/config.h` - I still got the error

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks! I did found `libfann2` to install using apt-get, but the include is not working, either with `-Ifann` or `-Ifann2`,  I still get the same error... :/

Comment: Time to run `find . -name config.h` and see what path it produces, if any.  If it produces something (say `./fann2/include/config.h`, then add `-I./fann2/include` (optionally with a space between the `I` and the `.`).  If it produces nothing, then you need to find the config.h file -- or you need to run configure etc to build the fann library.  That seems a bit unlikely for demo code, but it isn't completely impossible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the path is correct. Anyway, I did:
`$ find -name config.h`
results
`./fann/include/config.h`
and
`$ gcc fann/fixedfann.c -o fann/fixedfann.o -I./fann/include/config.h`
results
`cc1: warning: ./fann/include/config.h: not a directory [enabled by default]
fann/fixedfann.c:22:20: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Comment: Note the new error: note also that I didn't include `config.h` in the `-I./fann/include` I suggested.

Comment: You need the `-c` option when creating an object file (such as `fann/fixedfann.o`.  Omit the `-c` option when you want to link with `main.o` (or `main.c`), and list both object files.  That is: `gcc -c fann/fixedfann.c -o fann/fixedfann.o -I./fann/include/`; and then perhaps `gcc -o example main.o fann/fixedfann.o -lm` (not using a library for the `fann` code, but you haven't created it yet AFAICS).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler wow! finally I have a `.o` file! Thanks! I'll try to compile the whole thing now...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hey! I'm making some progress here, but I got stuck again. Do you have any hint about my update2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fellow helped me, and we came to this line that compiled everything, and make the executable:

```
$ gcc fann/fann.c fann/fann_io.c fann/fann_train.c fann/fann_train_data.c fann/fann_error.c fann/fann_cascade.c main.c -Ifann/include -lm
```

And this is the answer.

That said, this is exactly what `fixedfann.c` is doing (include all this `.c` files). But if I try:

```
$ gcc fann/fixedfann.c main.c -Ifann/include -lm
```

..I get:

```
undefined reference to `fann_train_on_file'
```

This `fann_train_on_file` is on `fann_train_data.c`, which is included by `fixedfann.c`, so why it is undefined? I don't know... :/

**--update**

I realized that:

```
$ gcc fann/fixedfann.c main.c -Ifann/include -lm
```

will work if I comment the headers on fixedfann.c:

```
//#include "config.h"
//#include "fixedfann.h"

#include "fann.c"
#include "fann_io.c"
#include "fann_train.c"
#include "fann_train_data.c"
#include "fann_error.c"
#include "fann_cascade.c"
```

Comment: I did two changes to your code -
1) In main.c change `#include "fann/include/fixedfann.h"` to `#include "fann.h"`
2) Change all occurrences of `fann.a` in `fann/Makefile` to `libfann.a`, as in the Makefile in my answer above.
Then use the following line to make your main program - `gcc main.c -I./fann/include -L./fann -lfann -o main`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ar` to make a static library and work with that.

Create a `Makefile` under your `hello-fann-3/fann/` folder with the following contents -

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
CFLAGS = -c -Iinclude

all: libfann.a

libfann.a: $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $^
```

Then use the `make` command in `hello-fann-3/fann/` to build the static library. The above `Makefile` will generate `libfann.a` that you can link to your program.

Create a `Makefile` under your `hello-fann-3/` folder with the following contents -

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
CFLAGS = -c -I./fann/include
LFLAGS = -L./fann -lfann

main: $(OBJECTS)
    gcc $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $^
```

Then use the `make` command in `hello-fann-3/` to build the `main` program.

In your `main.c`, you must include `fan.h` like -

```
#include "fann.h"
```

If you do not understand the Makefile, you can read about it here -

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I got `Makefile:8: *** missing separator.  Stop.` at line `ar rcs $@ $^` here... not sure why... By the way, is this recursive?

Comment: @Tom Brito, In the above makefile, the `ar` and `gcc` lines must begin with a tab character. It cannot be spaces! The Makefile is not recursive.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still doing something wrong here... I put the Makefile on ./src/fann folder (the headers are in ./src/fann/include, should I change this `-Iinclude`? but it compiled...), and looks like it compiled with no problem... Still, I got `main.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to fann_create_standard'` when I did `gcc -o output fann/fann.a main.c`. This `fann_create_standard` is on fann.c:32, I'm trying to find what I'm missing here...

Comment: @TomBrito, are your running your `make` command that builds `libfann.a` from `./src/fann/` folder? Looks like the file `fann.c` file is not compiled into `libfann.a` (I edited the above Makefile to change `fann.a` to `libfann.a`!)

Comment: Yes, I'm running the make from `./src/fann/`.

Comment: That is weird. I downloaded the FANN source from [here](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/download/), and after unzipping it, I had the FANN source at - `FANN-2.2.0-Source/src/`. Then I downloaded an example from [here](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/help/getting-started/), and put it as `example.c` at `FANN-2.2.0-Source/src/`. I copied the `Makefile` also at the same location, then built the library using this command - `make`, and the example using this command - `gcc example.c libfann.a -o example -Iinclude`. It got built and ran just fine!

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 32bits, in a Virtual Machine... I put my src here, and my attempts to compile, if you wanna check it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55384194/hello-fann-3.zip

Comment: OK. I will check your code and get back to you tomorrow (Saturday).

Comment: Hi @Tom, I have updated my above answer based on your directory structure. Try it, and let me know.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, not :/ I put the output as an update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to link the fann library.

1. If you compile manually do this

   ```
   gcc main.c -lfann -lm -o main
   ```

   then simply run it like

   ```
   ./main
   ```

   If you are on Ubuntu and you faced the following error

   > ./main: error while loading shared libraries: libfann.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

   Then run

   ```
   sudo ldconfig
   ```
2. If you are using NetBeans, then simply Right click on your project -> Properties -> Build -> Linker,
   then in the Libraries section click on the browse button [...] then in the new window click on Add Library...

   Then add fann library (for example my fann library path is: `/usr/local/lib/libfann.a`) and click Ok

Comment: Anyone who found this don't ignore the sudo ldconfig